# Onclick notification, start an activity in Android

Tags: android, class, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

I have a class for creating notifications. The class is like this:

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

     NotificationManager nm;

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      nm = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      CharSequence from = "Scheduled Training";
      CharSequence message = "Please attend the scheduled training";
      //Intent notifyIntent = new Intent();



      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);

      Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        "NeuroQ Scheduled Training", System.currentTimeMillis());
      notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
      nm.notify(1, notif);


     }
    }
```

I have an activity called: **QuizScreen**, which is required to be opened when the notification is clicked. I have tried using:

```
Intent quiz_intent = new Intent(TimeAlarm.this, QuizScreen.class);
                        TimeAlarm.this.startActivity(quiz_intent);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
The constructor Intent(TimeAlarm, Class<QuizScreen>) is undefined
```

Where am I going wrong? How should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Intent quiz_intent = new Intent(context, QuizScreen.class);` instead of `Intent quiz_intent = new Intent(TimeAlarm.this, QuizScreen.class);` For example,

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
  private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.android,"Time Reset!",System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, Second.class), 0);
    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Time changed", "Click on me to view my second activity", myIntent);
    notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The broadcast receiver does not count as a context?
Use the context parameter from the onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) instead

Comment: If you dont mind, can you please suggest some changes on the posted code?

Comment: it's the same as what Ankit just wrote

Answer (score 1):

try below code to start activity

```
Intent quiz_intent = new Intent(context, QuizScreen.class);
                        TimeAlarm.this.startActivity(quiz_intent);
```

Basically as Nicklas suggested, Receiver doesnt count as context, so u ll need to use context u getting in onReceive method, or use it like context.getApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

use :
`Intent quiz_intent = new Intent(context, QuizScreen.class);` instead of `Intent quiz_intent = new Intent(TimeAlarm.this, QuizScreen.class);`

For example:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.android,"Time Reset!",System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, Second.class), 0);
    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Time changed", "Click on me to view my second activity", myIntent);
    notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);`
```

Comment: you dont suppose to write answer  ur self. If somebody solved your query, just accept that!!